# How to solve " 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command" issue in visual studio 2017 community edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, 32bit-64bit, cl

I am trying to follow examples from [Gray Hat Hacking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071077316) where 32 bit C programs are compiled in visual studio. My issue is that visual studio 2017 developer prompt opens with errors like the following

```
'type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.isolation.ini"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
'dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\*.bat" /b /a-d-h /on' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also understand that I may have to add the location of cl in the environment variables and I may have to run the vcvarsall.bat file. I tried all these with no significant progress.

My objective is to compile and run 32 bit as well as 64 bit C programs on my 64 bit platform on visual studio. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Do you have the Visual C++ workloads installed for Visual Studio? (Open "Visual Studio Installer" from the start menu)

Comment: Okay, I got the problem partially solved. I added the required environment variables namely the path to cl.exe, which lies under the bin folder for host x64. I added the path to both user and system environment variables. Now, I have a question, inorder to run 32 bit programs on my 64 bit system, I should run the vcvars32.bat file isn't it?

Comment: @Dai, yeah I have installed the Visual C++ workloads, but which are the specific ones do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is running into the same problem, that I encountered. I found a solution to this problem, but I have no guarantee that this would work for everyone.

I must admit, configuring visual studio to run C programs is one heck of a job!!! One would go nuts trying to set up the right environment variables for a smooth execution of a C program. Once you install visual studio with the Build tools, the right SDKs (preferably the latest ones) and the latest VC++ toolset, the following environment variables will have to be set:

LIB
INCLUDE
PATH

Set these environment variables for both system and user (to be on the safe side) and if any file is missing, find its location (Most likely, their location would be in Windows Kits or somewhere within the Visual Studio folder. Expect some hunting!!!), then try to compile until it becomes successful.

If any one else has a better solution, I would request them to post it here!!!